# Onsen + Parallax

Tags: angularjs, parallax, onsen-ui

Both onsen & parallax are running, but parallax scroll events arent getting fired and when I turn off the onsen (from below code), it works just perfectly. I'm unable to figure out whats in onsen is causing the issue.

```
(function () {
     angular.module('gcc', [
     'onsen',
     'perfectParallax']);

     function px () {}
     angular
    .module('gcc')
    .controller('px', px);
})();
```

Comment: can you please tell me on which platform are you testing it?

Comment: @Andi Pavllo I'm testing on chrome (using device mode [iOS6 & Android]), also I'm using [link](https://github.com/hidefsk/angular-perfect-parallax/blob/master/angular-perfect-parallax.js)